# How to update multiple rows using single where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table test and the structure is as shown below

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
| id | is_deleted | sort_order | version | cid | pid  | qid  |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
| 14 |            |          6 |       0 |   1 |    2 |    7 |
| 18 |            |          1 |       2 |   1 |    4 |   12 |
| 26 |            |          9 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
| 40 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    5 |   18 |
| 49 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    5 |   35 |
| 50 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    5 |   39 |
| 51 |            |          4 |       0 |   1 |    5 |   40 |
| 61 |            |         10 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    2 |
| 62 |            |         11 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    3 |
| 63 |            |         12 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    4 |
| 64 |            |         13 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   42 |
| 65 |            |         14 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   43 |
| 66 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    4 |   26 |
| 67 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    4 |   38 |
| 71 |            |          7 |       0 |   1 |    2 |    2 |
| 72 |            |          8 |       0 |   1 |    2 |    8 |
| 73 |            |          9 |       0 |   1 |    2 |   50 |
| 74 |            |         10 |       0 |   1 |    2 |   51 |
| 76 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    3 |    9 |
| 78 |            |          4 |       0 |   1 |    3 |   53 |
| 79 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    6 |   54 |
| 80 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   11 |   59 |
| 81 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   12 |   70 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
```

I want to set version to 1 of all the rows whose cid =1,pid not equal to 6,11 and qid not equal to 28,59,54

Can anybody please tell me how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE test
SET `version` = 1
WHERE cid =1
  AND pid NOT in(6,11)
  AND qid NOT IN (28,59,54);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.I will check and let you know

Comment: cant it be done using `<>` actually I am getting qids from java in string format like `qid<>28 and qid<>59 and qid<>54`

Comment: Thanks I have found the solution